# how to convert date format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need jquery code for converting date format below is the example

i need to convert from FORMAT 1 to FORMAT 2

```
FORMAT 1: Wed Apr 20 07:05:00 PDT 2016 
FORMAT 2: 2016-04-20 07:23:42.476
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery doesn't handle date, javascript do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var DateCreated = new Date(Date.parse("Wed Apr 20 07:05:00 PDT 2016")).format("yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s");
```

Comment: There is no native `Date.prototype.format()` method. I guess you are referring to any external lib (moment js???)

Comment: @Dhara  .format() is not working. because im not using supported extnl lib js for this. so can u give some other way without extnl lib